# Quantifying the success probability of brute force attack against (search) LPN

Tags: brute-force-attack, complexity, probability

I've been trying to learn about attacks on LPN ($n$-bit secret, noise rate $\eta$), and have found several allusions to a brute force algorithm  that runs in time exponential in $n$ and requires a linear number of samples in $n$. For example, the third slide of this [deck](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.724.4038&rep=rep1&type=pdf) or the original [BKW paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0010022.pdf). That said, I have not been able to find the success probability of this algorithm, nor derive it myself.

LPN challenger:

- upon initialization, chooses random $s \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$
- when queried, chooses random $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$, computes $c = a \cdot s \mod{2}$ and returns the true $(a, c)$ with probability $1 - \eta$, or the corrupted $(a, 1 \oplus c)$ with probability $\eta$.

Bruteforce algorithm:

- query the LPN challenger for $m$ labelled samples $(x_1, l_1),...,(x_m, l_m) \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n \times \mathbb{Z}_2$
- for each potential secret $s_j \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$, compute the empirical error rate $r_j = (1/m) (\sum_{i=1}^m (x_i \cdot s_j) + l_i \mod{2})$ (note each term of the sum is computed $\mod{2}$ but the sum itself is computed over the integers)
- output potential secret $s_t$ with empirical error rate $r_t$ closest to the noise rate $\eta$ (i.e. $t = arg\,min_t \lvert r_t - \eta \rvert$)

Intuitively, it seems this algorithm should succeed with probability significantly better than the trivial $\frac{1}{2^n}$ probability of guessing at random. But I'm not really sure how to quantify the success probability here. Any pointers to the literature or direct answers appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm not 100% positive the last step of the bruteforce is actually the algorithm referenced in the literature, as the phrases I've seen used are "check which s is the best fit" and "find the one of least empirical error". So if I'm mistaken on the bruteforce algorithm description, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest if we simply pick the secret with the lowest score (which is also the maximum likelihood explanation). In this case, I can write down the cumbersome exact expression and then it is a question of which approximation you might like to use. Let's dispense with the $1/m$ factor in the score.

### Exact expression

Note that for the causal solution $s_t$ the score $r_t$ is distributed $\mathrm{Bin}(m,\eta)$. We also note that the test is only likely to succeed when the score of the causal solution is bigger than the maximum of the non-causal scores. The non-causal scores should be distributed $\mathrm{Bin}(m,0.5)$ and the chance that one of these is less than or equal to some bound $r$ is given by $F(r;m,0.5)$ where $F$ is the [binomial cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). Therefore the chance that all $2^n-1$ non-causal answers are greater than $r$ is given by
$$(1-F(r;m,0.5))^{2^n-1}.$$

Summing over possible values of $r_t$ we see that the probability that the causal score is greater than all of the non-causal scores is given by
$$\sum_{r=1}^m\left(1-F(r;m,0.5)\right)^{2^n-1}\left({m\atop r}\right)\eta^r(1-\eta)^{m-r}.$$

### Approximations and bounds

$F$ is tiresome to calculate and so you may wish to approximate it with either [Chernoff or Hoeffding bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds). It's also not the worst plan in the world to bound the above sum from below with the probability that $r_t$ is less than or equal to some fixed bound $r$ (given by $F(r;m,\eta)$) times the probability that the minimum of the non-causal scores is greater than the same fixed bound $r$:
$$\left(1-F(r;m,0.5)\right)^{2^n-1}F(r;m,\eta).$$
A good choice of $r$ in this case might be $r\approx\eta m-2\sqrt{m\eta(1-\eta)}$ so that $F(r;m,\eta)\approx 0.95$ or simply $r\approx(1-\eta)m$ so that $F(r;m,\eta)\approx 0.5$.